# Find the value of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

Tags: polynomials

If the real numbers $x, y, z$ are such that $x^2 +4y^2 +16z^2=48$ and $xy+4yz+2zx=24$, What is the value 0f $x^2+y^2+z^2 ?$.

The value of $x+2y+4z = \left\lvert 12 \right\rvert$. I don't know how to proceed after that.

Comment: How did you find the value of $x+2y+4z$? And what is $|12|$ supposed to signify? Isn't that just $12$?

Comment: How about solving $x$, $y$, $z$ from what you've given and then plugging them to either of the two equations given or into $x^2+y^2+z^2$? I'd expect the general way to study these things to be to first try to simplify the equations that you've been given.

Comment: @Arthur  $(x+2y+4z)^2$ can be expanded out to $x^2+4y^2+16z^2+4(xy+2xz+4yz)$, which is equal to 48+4*24=144. So  $(x+2y+4z)^2=144$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$x^2+4y^2+16z^2=48$$
$$xy+4yz+2zx=24$$
Now,
$$2(x^2+4y^2+16z^2)-4(xy+4yz+2zx)=0$$
$$(x-2y)^2+(2y-4z)^2+(x-4z)^2=0$$
Let say $x=2y=4z=k$
$$x=k,y=\frac k2,z=\frac k4$$
Since $k^2+\frac{4k^2}{4}+\frac{16k^2}{16}=48$
$$k=4$$
$$x=4,y=2,z=1$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=16+4+1=21$$

Comment: You could also have $k=-4$

Comment: @MarkBennet But then $x^2+y^2+z^2$ would be the same.

Comment: @egreg true, but I think it should be said. The answer is a good one.